# Question about cylinders of mixed gases (nitrogen and carbon dioxide)

Tags: gas

This is probably a question more suited towards the home brewing stack exchange, but I'm interested in some of the engineering and physics aspects of this as well, so I'll just try asking it here first.

I recently acquired a 5-liter cylinder of blended gas (N<sub>2</sub>+CO<sub>2</sub>, also known as beer gas) that I use for dispensing beer. The ratio is 70% nitrogen and 30% carbon dioxide. I got it from the local welder and has a pressure of 200 bar. During my trials, I've found the beer to get over carbonated, which should be impossible with the temperature and pressure parameters if the blend was really 70/30 N<sub>2</sub>+CO<sub>2</sub>.

I have a few questions:

- At a room temperature of 21 °C/70 °F and a pressure of 200 bar, does CO<sub>2</sub> liquify and fall to the bottom? In this case, would it be just CO<sub>2</sub> coming out of the cylinder, (considering there is a dip tube/siphon/mixing tube going to the bottom) explaining the over carbonation?
- Do mixed gas cylinders require a dip tube/siphon/mixing tube at all?

Comment: How are you measuring the carbonation? Change in pH or just amount of gas in the liquid? CO2 does not liquify in substantial quantities at room temperatures and any reasonable pressure.  It is however a much denser gas compared to Nitrogen.